# VS2015 .net framework versions are not listed while creating new project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, .net-framework-version

After installing vs2015 with updates on window10, I am not able to select targeting .net framework versions although they are installed and listed on programs and features. .net framework versions are not listing on Create new project window.

I am not able to understand the problem over here. It was working fine previously. Tried to reinstall the vs2015 still same issue. Please need help to solve the issue.

Installed framework versions:
[Installed framework versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pcjnv.png)

Framework versions are not available on create new project window.
[framework versions are not available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vscpP.png)

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to update windows 10?

Comment: @oneNiceFriend windows 10 is also up to date. Everything is updated. Cant figure out cause of the issue.